# AIML multiple patterns with one response

Tags: chatbot, aiml

Lets say I want the user to have a single response to multiple greetings for the bot. Is there a better way to write this using an "or" statement or a list instead of writing each case out with all the templating like this to redirect the pattern?

```
<category>
    <pattern> HELLO</pattern>
    <template>
        Hello User!
    </template>
</category>

 <category>
    <pattern> HI</pattern>
    <template>
        <srai> HELLO</srai>
    </template>
</category>

     <category>
    <pattern> HOWDY</pattern>
    <template>
        <srai> HELLO</srai>
    </template>
</category>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a set called "greetings" containing the different ways of saying hello, like this:

[image]

And then write this category:

```
<category>
    <pattern>^ <set>greetings</set> ^</pattern>
    <template>Hello User!</template>
</category>
```

But to me, it's far easier to make new categories for each option and <srai> to your main one, as in your original example.